# I need to find the value of x. Im only given the a degree how would you solve this?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

this is the link to the triangle that is connected to the question.
What is the value x?

Comment: what do you know about base angles of an isosceles triangle ?

Answer (score 1):

The triangle is isosceles so the other two angles are the same.

Since all the angles in a triangle add up to $180^\circ$ then those angles are $70^\circ$ each. Now, $x$ is the suplementary angle to one of them i.e. $70^\circ + x = 180^\circ$ therefore $x = 110^\circ$